# 7za ax (add files excluding) syntax at macOS console.

Tags: macos, command-line, 7zip

7za help lists the following switches for including/excluding files in the archive:

```
  -ai[r[-|0]]{@listfile|!wildcard}: Include archives
  -ax[r[-|0]]{@listfile|!wildcard}: eXclude archives
```

Suppose I want to pack `My Directory` to `MyArchive.zip` excluding subdirectory `Irrelevant`.

I tried the following

7za -ax"My Directory/Irrelevant" -tzip MyArchive.zip "My Directory"

7za a -x"My Directory/Irrelevant" -tzip MyArchive.zip "My Directory"

7za a -x@"My Directory/Irrelevant" -tzip MyArchive.zip "My Directory"

7za a -x"@My Directory/Irrelevant" -tzip MyArchive.zip "My Directory"

7za a -x"Irrelevant" -tzip MyArchive.zip "My Directory"

Neither of those is recognised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
7za a -x\!"My Directory/Irrelevant/*" -tzip MyArchive.zip "My Directory"
```

or even this

```
7za a -x\!"My Directory/Irrelevant" -tzip MyArchive.zip "My Directory"
```

Note the '\' before exclamation mark, as otherwise bash will treat '!' as an event. Tried to put '!' under quotes - didn't work.